# Comment an equation without creating extra space

Tags: math-mode, align

I try to make a comment on the right (or left) of one line of proof. But the `align*` environment automatically move the whole equations to the left to leave space for the comment. But I still want the equations to be in the center (the comment is short enough that it won't be conflicting the equations). How could I achieve this?

To be more specific,
I used the code

```
 \begin{align*}
 equation0 &= equation1
           &= equation2
           &= equation3 && \text{make a comment here}
           &= equation4
\end{align*}
```

I just want to put `\text{make a comment here}` on the right without affecting the original alignment of the equations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Omit the `&&` and use `\rlap{\text{make a comment here}}`, which causes the comment to have no width "to the right", meaning it starts at the same place but doesn't actually take up any space in the alignment.  For a comment on the left, use `\llap` instead of `\rlap`, which causes leftward space to be ignored.

In response to the question in the comment: in `align*` or `equation*` specifically (or any other unnumbered environment) you can hijack the "equation label" to contain a comment by using `\tag*{\text{make a comment here}}` rather than `\rlap`.  This will place the comment on the left if `amsmath` was loaded with the `leqno` option.  In a numbered equation, it is not a good idea to put something flush right.

Comment: By the way, do you know how to make the "\rlap{\text{make a comment here}}" thing to the rightmost? It seems that \hfill or \raggedright does not work.

Comment: Added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But before today I always used amsart and \tag to make comments on equations (by default of amsart, \tag appears on the left). But this time the comment is a bit longer that makes the equations move to the right.

Comment: As long as the comment is short enough that it would not actually overlap the equation, you could use `\rlap` or `\llap` *with* `\tag*` to make the tag have effective width zero.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that works. And it seems that I need to use \tag*{\rlap{comment}} when the comment is on the left.

Comment: True; that's because a comment on the left is left-aligned when flushleft, but right-aligned when "just left of the equation".  The real use of `\llap` and `\rlap` is to create text of width zero that is flush left or right (respectively) relative to its position in the line.

Comment: Instead of `\rlap{...}` I would recommend `\makebox[0pt][l]{...}` that's slightly less efficient but also less surprising in other contexts (try starting a paragraph with `\rlap`).

Comment: (The answer to egreg's puzzle is that the `\rlap`ped text will not be part of the paragraph it "starts", since it's in a box, which doesn't end vertical mode)

Comment: You know, this is a rare instance where I stick with the plain TeX version of a construct for which LaTeX has a more intelligent alternative because I didn't know the original was deprecated.  This kind of thing happens a lot when you learn TeX from the internet, though I understand LaTeX3 will basically fix the problem by not supporting plain TeX.